# Form's background image (size more than 20MB) not loading in win xp

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-interface

I am using **Windows XP** os. When i try to add image (which has size of 22.8 MB) in form's background it shows error like

> 'token endelement in state error would result in an invalid xml
>   document'

before running the form...but in **Windows 7** it works fine... can anyone help me  to solve this problem in **Win XP**...

Comment: When you run it, does it run with the image? And are you getting any other errors? Also are you adding these images into the resource file?

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR I just added that file through local resource, i did not add it via project resource file, By the way when i'm running my project the image is not getting displayed. [the error i specified in the question is raising all the time. ]. Thanks...!

Comment: Ok, add the file through resources then...

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR i add that file in project resource..it loads fine..but i am using following code to avoid flickering in form..  `Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
        Get
            Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or &H2000000
            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property`
when i use this code,the image not loaded in my form...

Comment: There shouldn't be any flickering, you may have low memory... Did you check my answer? Also if I helped you, please make sure to vote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to increase the virtual memory on the XP Machine...

- Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
- Click Performance and Maintenance, and then click System.
- On the Advanced tab, under Performance, click Settings.
- On the Advanced tab, under Virtual memory, click Change.
- Under Drive [Volume Label], click the drive that contains the paging file that you want to change.
- Under Paging file size for selected drive, click to Custom size check box. You can enter the amount of memory you would like to reserve for Virtual memory by entering the initial and maximum size.
- Click Set
  When you are prompted to restart the computer, click Yes.
  Special Note: You should choose the same amount for the initial size and maximum size. This will Stop your CPU from constantly changing the paging file.

If this doesn't work, use the applications resources to add your image into the project...

Thanks!